# changing of differentials in an equation

Tags: derivatives

This doubt may be trivial to some people but i am a little confused. In the derivation for kinetic energy we change the differential $\frac{d\vec v}{dt}.d\vec r=\frac{d\vec r}{dt}.d\vec v$. My question is when are we allowed to do such differential change and what rules are applied. Also, is it different for cross products?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\#$ be a bilinear operation, e.g. dot or cross product. The we formally have 
$$du \# v' = (u' \, dt) \# v' = (u' \# v') \, dt = u' \# (v' \, dt) = u' \# dv$$

Answer (score 0):

It's allowed in the case at hand. One has
$$\dot r=v,\quad dr=v\>dt,\quad dv=\dot v\>dt$$
and therefore
$$\dot v\cdot dr=(\dot v\cdot v)\>dt=\dot r\cdot dv\ .$$

Comment: @md2perpe: Thank you, but I don't like the arrows $\ldots$

Comment: I removed my comment when I saw that you had modified your post.

Comment: I don't like the arrows very much either, but sometimes they can be handy, especially if the audience is used to them and will be confused otherwise.